# Filter call hierarchy by source folder

Tags: java, eclipse

This is related to [Filter Eclipse's "Open Call Hierarchy" to just my company/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962195/filter-eclipses-open-call-hierarchy-to-just-my-company-project).

In my Maven project, I use the same package names for both code and tests, but they're in different source folders (`main/java` and `test/java`). However, I can't find the option to filter by source folder.

I can filter out some test methods because the class names ends with "Tests", but this is not always the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Working Set to control the search scope. In the **Call Hierarchy** view, click the options button (small white triangle in the upper-right corner of the view) and select *Search Scope* > *Working Set*. There you can define a new Working Set that only includes the source folder(s) you want.

Working Sets are a universal feature in Eclipse; they can be used in many places to limit the scope of actions, searches, etc.